# Timer to alternate image in wp7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

In my xaml file, I have two images:

```
<Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" >
  <Image  Source="Images/FlightSearchImg.png"></Image>
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="ParisLive">
  <Image Source="Images/ServiceTileImg.png"></Image>
</Grid>
```

I need to use a timer to alternate the visibility of images.
How can I show  image1  and hide image2 for 5 secondes and after alternate to show image2 and  hide image1 for 5 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried a storyboard yet with a GeneratedDuration set on the VisualTransition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a timer and when it reaches 5000 milliseconds toggle the image and.

Set variables...

```
// Timer Stuff
    static Boolean stopped = true;
    static long dd = 0, hh = 0, mm = 0, ss = 0, ms = 0, gtdd = 0, gthh = 0, gtmm = 0, gtss = 0;
    static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    Timer timer;
    bool ShowImage1 = true;
```

Start the timer when you're ready. Notice the updateDisplay function, which we'll add next.

```
stopwatch.Start();
timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(updateDisplay), AdventureTimer, 0, 100);
```

Create your updateDisplay function. In here you'll check to see which image to show.

```
public void updateDisplay(Object displayBlock)
    {
       if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 5000) {
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(ToggleImage);
       }
    }
```

Create a function to toggle the image.

```
public void ToggleImage()
    {
        stopwatch.Reset();
        if (ShowImage1 == true)
        {
            ImageGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ParisLive.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ShowImage1 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ImageGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ParisLive.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ShowImage1 = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go the XAML route, you can simply implement one using the [Dispatch Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615945%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  You simply set the image source every 5 minutes, and cycle through each Uri.